# Technological word for Code Branch, or Region?

Tags: synonyms, programming

Looking for a word that describes a section, or branch of computer code.

In this instance, I am assigning numerical ID's to system alarms, and I want to differentiate each section of alarms based on where the alarms are coming from.

Each different section will have a commented line that reads something like:

"Log Monitor 'branch or cluster'"
or
"Process Monitor 'branch or section'"

Trying to come up with a succinct word to describe what I'm separating the code blocks into.

Comment: It depends on how big the "code cluster" is. Do you have a separate function? A separate class? A separate module? Or if you're working with Dynamically Linked Libraries (dll's), perhaps it's its own library? Your question appears to be too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would leave it as "Log Monitor" / "Process Monitor" in this case. I don't think any further differentiation is needed; simply having those is fine in most cases but it's hard to tell without the code. Want to update with a link to part of the code [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)? :)

Regardless, the word "case" would be used for something like:

```
case monitor_type
when "log_monitor"
  blah
when "process_monitor"
  bleh
end
```

Although I believe the general word for "section of code" is "module" or "component".

Comment: Each "block" is actually just an arrangement of arrays that get called by an alarm function, and the commented line is just to make sure when other alarms are created, they don't overlap with other alarms. But I will probably just end up leaving the names as just the names as you suggested.